# X is not a class template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to compile the below code, and I am getting the error as

> "error: ‘MD5Sum’ is not a class template
>   template<> struct MD5Sum<::cv_bridge::CvImage>"

```
template<> struct MD5Sum<::cv_bridge::CvImage>
{
  static const char* value() { return MD5Sum<::sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::value(); }
  static const char* value(const ::cv_bridge::CvImage&) { return value(); }

  static const uint64_t static_value1 = MD5Sum<::sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::static_value1;
  static const uint64_t static_value2 = MD5Sum<::sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::static_value2;

  // If the definition of sensor_msgs/Image changes, we'll get a compile error here.
  ROS_STATIC_ASSERT(MD5Sum<::sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::static_value1 == 0x060021388200f6f0ULL);
  ROS_STATIC_ASSERT(MD5Sum<::sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::static_value2 == 0xf447d0fcd9c64743ULL);
};
```

This seems to be template specialization. Does it means that template class should be present first before make template specialization out of it.

Comment: "Does it means that template class should be present first before make template specialization out of it?" Sure...

Comment: so you've answered your own question.

Comment: I have added the below code above, but still the same issue:
`
template <typename T>
struct MD5Sum<T>
{
    static const char* value() { return MD5Sum<T>::value(); }
    static const char* value(T&) { return value(); }
 
    static const uint64_t static_value1;
    static const uint64_t static_value2;
};
`

Comment: @Ghansham The correct syntax to define template should be `template <typename T> struct MD5Sum { ...`.

Comment: @Ghansham That is still a template specialisation - leave `<T>` after the struct name to get a non-specialised one...

Comment: i have done that...check 3rd comment, is it not the proper one? Please post the correct template code in answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class template `MD5Sum` needs to be declared before any of its specializations. 
You either need to include the file where the template is declared, or declare it yourself.

You can use an empty definition (if you only want to call fully specialized versions) or the generic implementation you choose:

```
// add this before your specialization
template <class T> struct MD5Sum; // empty declaration

// or your default implementation
template <class T> struct MD5Sum {
   ...
};
```